# Is there an easy way to determine what a file is by its extension in C#? 

Tags: c#, file, file-association

Is there an easy way to determine what a file is by its extension in C#? For example if I pass a file extension of ".txt" then it will return "Text Document" or if I pass it ".pdf" it will return "Adobe Acrobat Reader". I see this behavior built into Windows Explorer, under the "Type" column. Is there a way to mimic this in C#?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to get what explorer actually shows and are willing to use COM inter-op you can use the Shell.Application class to get it with the minimum amount of code. If you go to add a reference, browse to X:\windows\system32\shell32.dll that will import shell32's type library. Then just use the code:

```
string GetFileType(string path)
{
   Shell32.ShellClass shell = new Shell32.ShellClass();
   Shell32.Folder folder = shell.NameSpace(Path.GetDirectoryName(path));

   Shell32.FolderItem item = folder.ParseName(Path.GetFileName(path));
   return folder.GetDetailsOf(item, 2);
}
```

Comment: This seems to work perfect. Will this work in all versions of Windows? XP, Vista and Windows 7?

Comment: It should do, the COM object has been around for ages. But I have only personally tried that code on 7.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Registry class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry.aspx) to query the HKCR hive.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this class

[C# FileAssociation Class](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/AF_FileAssociation.aspx)

Answer (score -3):

Check the registry; you can get that data from there

Comment: Thats a bit broad. How about some links?

Comment: I figured googling c# "registry filetype" isn't Brian surgery

Comment: Same goes for rocket haha, sorry I had to.