# C# - get Windows association for a random file

Tags: c#, .net

In C#, I'm trying to take some random file selected by a user, and determine the Windows Association for the program.

I'd like to use this to provide some helpful information to the user about the program which will run.

This is a portfolio tool where generic files can be attached to a record.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851520/file-associations-in-c.

Comment: I'd disagree. 185120 only wanted the string "Text File" for a .txt file. pearcewg looks to want more than that.

Comment: Take a closer look at the answers provided in that question.

Comment: Answers yes, question no. The **question** isn't a duplicate, even if the answers in that other question are applicable to this question. I think the key differentiator is that pearcewg wants "the program which will run", which has potentially different answers than just obtaining the text value from the Type column in explorer

Comment: @Dan and @Jason: one of my issues with SO.  I'd prefer to be able to find answers by looking at the question titles, instead of so frequently digging through tons of comments looking for anything tangential which might help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I programmatically check file that a file association exists before attempting to Process.Start() it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6086973/how-can-i-programmatically-check-file-that-a-file-association-exists-before-atte)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[1851520](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851520/file-associations-in-c) is a similar question, and from that question [C# AF_FileAssociations](http://affileassociations.codeplex.com/) looks to have what you need.

Failing that, [System File Association](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/System_File_Association.aspx) on Codeproject looks to have the code to retrieve file association info.